# How to center a text line within an itemize environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

How to center a text line within an itemize enivornment ?

What I tried:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{itemize}
  \item {\centering text to center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

But the text is not centered, but on the left.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item {\hfil text to center}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\item \hfil text to center` would be enough. The latter `\hfil` is removed by the end of paragraph and replaced by `\parfilskip`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thank you for noting. I changed the answer appropriately. :-)